# Using reactjs, updating an item in a list without updating the whole list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

I'm using React and Reflux. And I'm having a hard time figuring out how to update one comment in a list of comments.

I'm confused on where state should go.  I put the state at the top in CommentsList.  Thinking it the React way.  And then CommentsItem is just props.  And then each CommentsItem has a LikeButton, which I made props as well.

The problem is when I call the like action in the LikeButton, it reloads all the comments in CommentsStore.  I'm guessing I need a new store that loads one comments instead of all comments?  But then does that mean I'm putting state in CommentsItem?  I'm kind of confused on the best practice here.

This is what I'm working with:

**`<ProfilePage />`**

```
<div>
    <ProfileBox profile={this.state.profile} />
    <CommentsList query={{profile: this.state.profile._id}} />
</div>
```

**`<CommentsList />`**

```
var CommentsList = React.createClass({

  mixins: [
    Reflux.connect(CommentsStore, 'comments')
  ],

  componentWillMount: function() {
    CommentsActions.load(this.props.query);
  },

  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.state.comments.map(function (comment, i) {
      return (
        <CommentsItem key={i} comment={comment} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

**`<CommentsItem />`**

```
var CommentsItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.props.comment.user.username}:
          {this.props.comment.comment}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.comment.numPoints} people like this
        </div>
        <div>
          OTHER LINKS
          <LikeButton commentId={this.props.comment._id} liked={this.props.comment.liked} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**`<LikeButton />`**

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass({

  handleLike: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CommentsActions.like(this.props.commentId);
  },

  render: function() {
    var likeText = this.props.liked ? 'Unlike' : 'Like';
    return(
      <a href="#" onClick={this.handleLike}>{likeText}</a>
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: I think this is best practice. Because you are looping through the commentlist with `map` but react only performs the necessary DOM operations. Some JS loops are faster than more DOM operations.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I'm an idiot. I saw that it was updating the time fields on some other posts so I thought it was updating all posts.  That's awesome that it only updates the necessary ones! Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I think this is best practice. Because you are looping through the commentlist with map but react only performs the necessary DOM operations. Some JS loops are faster than more DOM operations." –  Dustin Hoffner

Answer (score 1):

The best things to do would be to change this line:

```
<CommentsItem key={i} comment={comment} />
```

to

```
<CommentsItem key={comment._id} comment={comment} />
```

as react uses the key to determine whether something has changed, by using the iterator, adding a new element to anywhere except the end of the comments list would require react to rerender every comment.

see here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children for more details.

Comment: if the comment list already is an object with `{'id1': {...}, 'id2': {...} }` this is useless